# Extracting String Php array time from an array

Tags: php

I have a CSV file that contains data in the following format:

```
12:00:04am,26.3,60.7,599,2665,4095
12:00:09am,26.3,60.7,599,2665,4095
```

I have many lines of data in the same format. Now, what I am trying to do is to take user input as a time and search for that time in the CSV file. Then, I want to print all the data that is available after that time.

I am able to read the CSV file, but I am having trouble comparing the user's input time with the time in the CSV file because the user's input will be in the form of a string.

So, my approach is as follows:

```
$open = fopen("data.csv", "r");
$data = fread($open, filesize("data.csv"));
$data_newline = explode("\n", $data);
print_r($data_newline);
```

This code returns data in the following format:

```
Array ( [0] => 12:00:04am,26.3,60.7,599,2665,4095 [1] => 12:00:09am,26.3,60.7,599,2665,4095
```

Now, I need to take user input as a time, which is in the first position of every line in the CSV file, and check if that time is available. If it is available, I need to print all the data that comes after that time.

I am trying something like converting a csv time into time format and then comparing with the user input .

Comment: You want to convert both values into a datetime type, take care of standardizing the timezone and then compare those two objects. Or, alternatively, you convert only the user input into a datetime type, take care of the timezone and then compare a formatted string conversion result with the value in that table.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your csv rows has unique time value for each row. Below code will give you first matched row data.

```
$csvArray = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));
$inputValue = '12:00:04am';
$matchedResult = [];

$index = array_search($inputValue, array_column($csvArray, 0));
if(!empty($index)){
    $matchedResult = $csvArray[$index];
}

print_r($matchedResult);
```